# how to customize django forms and success message without bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm currently making a registration page. I'm using django's registration form and message alert. However, i do not use Bootstrap and would not like to use Bootstrap. How am i able to customize my registration form and message alerts with pure CSS?

Here I provide the code to my message alerts:

**base.html**

```
<div class="alert">  
{% if messages %}  
{% for message in messages %}  
{{message}}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Thank you for registering, {username}.')
            return redirect('conference:index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I've tried adding the "alert" class into the CSS, however it does not work at all. Is there something I'm missing out in order to make the CSS styling work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following-

**base.css**

```
ul.messages {
    margin:10px 100px;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:
    none;
}
ul.messages li.success,
ul.messages li.warning,
ul.messages li.error,
ul.messages li.info {
    margin:0;
    padding:14px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.messages li.success { background:#81ce81; }
ul.messages li.success a { color:#0ac33e; }

ul.messages li.error { background:#a30029; color:#e9828e; }
ul.messages li.error a { color:#e9828e; }

ul.messages li.info { background:#faffae; color:#696b4e; }
ul.messages li.info a { color:#1586de; }

ul.messages li.warning { background:#de9404; }
ul.messages li.warning a { color:#f49000; }

ul.messages li a.close {
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    opacity:1;
    border:0;
    box-shadow:none;
    text-shadow:none;
}

.login-form {
    float:left;
}
```

**base.html**

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message|safe }}
                <a href="#" class="close">x</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

*(Reference to the above is from Antonio Mele's book "Django 3 By Example")*